# Cannot locate .Rprofile file

Tags: r, osx-mountain-lion, rstudio

I want to add some customization to my .Rprofile. However, I cannot seem to find the file.

Many have said it is located in my ~/ folder. I have unhidden all my hidden files and do not seem to find it. Also looked in R.Frameworks.

Not finding anything. I assume that I have one, as R fires up and works fine.

Any other search methods?

My system is Mac OSX 10.8, R 3.0, RStudio

Comment: if there isn't one, just create it. `touch ~/.Rprofile`

Comment: ok. Just write in a text file or some other document type? Then put in in ~/   ?

Comment: yep. this file is _optional_. Note that the document type should be plain text, and with no file extension obviously.

Comment: @flodel. There may be a duplicate somewhere, but that's not it. If a dup does exist, it is probably tagged with a [osx] tag. This is really a question about a) is .Rprofile necessary [No] as well as b) how to see/build it [mac-specific instructions needed].

Comment: @baptiste thanks for the info. Since so many people have spoken about that file- I just assume I must have one. So, I will create this and see what occurs. Very kind.

Answer (score 17):

my favorite way would be to open a Terminal window, and type:

```
touch ~/.Rprofile
open ~/.Rprofile
```

or

```
open -a Textedit ~/.Rprofile
```

this way you save yourself from  a) the possibility of overwriting an existing file that you didn't find; b) fiddling with the way the Finder hides/shows system files; c) problems with overzealous text editors/OS that insist on adding file extensions, or don't like system files.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using OS X:

in text edit -

- new file
- put in whatever you'd like to have in your rprofile
- Format > Make Plain Text  (or CMD+SHIFT+T )
- Save File
  ** IMPORTANT: *un-select* the option to add ".txt"
- Save the file as .Rprofile  (it will give you a warning, say yes)

Answer (score 0):

Terminal:

```
cd <wherever your R stuff is> [enter]

grep -r "some_string_you_know_exists_in_.Rprofile" [enter]
```

This will recursively search the directory and all subdirectories for any files containing the string in quotations

Comment: Good point, I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Your .Rprofile file may not exist. It's not necessary. If it does exist, then the Finder.app hides it (as well as hiding the .RHistory file), since it thinks its a "system file". You can force Finder.app to always display system files by executing this in a Terminal session. (This is how I run my box.) I guess you already did something like this?

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

# After running  <pt>-<click-hold> on Dock-Finder-icon, choose relaunch
```

Running with this does require the discipline of never deleting system files unless you really know all their dependencies. Then you can create a .Rprofile file and edit it when you want to add something. Going back to the safe version would use the obvious modification.

Comment: to look I did this in the terminal: 

defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE && killall Finder

But still found nothing.

Comment: Even better. It is possible to have multiple .Rprofile files with different working directories.