# In Jupyter with R, display by default all rows and columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-lab, linux-mint, jupyter-irkernel

I'm looking for a way to display all the rows and all the columns **BY DEFAULT** in Jupyter, without the `...`, in specific in Jupyter Lab but possibly is something done the same way in Jupyter Notebook.

[image: Sample of truncated dataframe in R in Jupyter]

I already had this setting and wouldn't need to add `options()` like in many other posts. However, I needed to do a fresh install of my Linux Mint and lost it.

I'm not totally sure, but I think it was related with creating a startup script and increasing the values for both rows and columns or it could be something to add in the settings. My best finding was this:

[Where can I put a startup script in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818538/where-can-i-put-a-startup-script-in-jupyter)

I DON'T need it for Pandas and I DON'T need it as an option in every cell I create.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see all rows of a data frame in a Jupyter notebook with an R kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383591/how-to-see-all-rows-of-a-data-frame-in-a-jupyter-notebook-with-an-r-kernel)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are right, the solution involves adding `options()` to the startup script. I linked to the canonical answer which describes what to put into `options()`. I do not know how to invoke a script specifying options on start-up. I would search with IRkernel phrase.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration @krassowski !

As jankatins points [here](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/356), it's something that could be added to the `~/.Rprofile`.

I didn't have it and created it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459353/cannot-locate-rprofile-file):

`touch ~/.Rprofile`
`open ~/.Rprofile`

and just added the solution by @dfrankow without extra addition. Correct me if I'm wrong because it looks too simple, but I even restarted the kernel, cleaned output and restarted Linux and now the dataframes appear fully displayed in the cells.

Comment: Also found that `options(repr.matrix.max.rows=600, repr.matrix.max.cols=200)` affects all the cells. So, it could be something to run as first cell in the notebook making unnecessary to do all above, but in the end I consider is good to know about this small tweaks.